# course on udemy provide react native with version 0.33?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I started learning react native with current version 0.57 and I found course on udemy with version with 0.33. so is it good for exploring react native?

Comment: Please check stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: These tutorials are good to kick start. Version doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

To get the feel of react-native environment and basics the version of RN does not matter. Every now and then react native releases updates to improve it. At your level it shouldn't matter much. You can go ahead and take the course but try to be informed and updated about the new features and updates. Join other communities like GitHub. Its not possible for instructors at udemy or any other platform to make individual courses for every RN version its very hard to keep up. I myself took a course from udemy and it was outdated version of RN the instructor was teaching but it was not problematic, sure few things had changed since the time course was made but i caught up on those things by research.